# Как проверить, есть ли изображение по ссылке Kotlin/Java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Загружаю изображение через Picasso

```
Picasso.get().load(image_url).into(imageview)
```

https://starwars-visualguide.com/assets/img/planets/1.jpg
Вот, например, нерабочая ссылка. Пытался этими 2мя способами:

```
Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches()

URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)
```

Но они оба в этом случае возвращают true. То есть изображения там нет, но ссылка то как бы есть.

Comment: Для этого необходимо запросить изображение по ссылке.

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: Послать GET запрос на URL.

Comment: *Загружаю изображение через Picasso* `Picasso.get().load(image_url)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25749575/5479247

Comment: Ну как бы если возвращает true то изображение там есть.

Comment: @soundsofnature Валидная ссылка не означает, что под ней что-то есть. Означает лишь то, что синтаксис ссылки правильный.

Answer (score 0):

Отправьте GET запрос и убедитесь, что статус ответа успешный, а также, что Content-Type ответа является изображением.